# Cancel All PrintJobs of a PrintService

Tags: java, printing

I want to write a java application which cancels every PrintJob of the Default Printer.

I get my default printer with

```
PrintService m_Printer = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

But i can't find any solution to get every PrintJob of the PrintService.
And when i don't have access to all the PrintJobs, i can't cancel them.
It seems easy, but impossible. Even google was not able to help.
Any idea?